# MySQL return value from another referenced row in the same table

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a table looking something like this:

```
+----+--------------+-------+----------------+------------+
| id | product_name | price | bulk_reference | bulk_count |
+----+--------------+-------+----------------+------------+
| 1  | xxxx         | 11.99 | 0              | 0          |
+----+--------------+-------+----------------+------------+
| 2  | zzzz         | 22.99 | 0              | 0          |
+----+--------------+-------+----------------+------------+
| 3  |              |       | 2              | 10         |
+----+--------------+-------+----------------+------------+
```

I can select all the products etc, no problem. However - what I need to do is returning all the products, but lines WHERE bulk_reference > 0 need to return the referenced row values that are unset in the row... In the same result set.

I need to do it for certain fields. So let's say I want to select the `product_name` field for ID 3. It should return `zzzz` as the `bulk_reference` field is set to 2, so it should take the value from row ID=2.

How can I do this with MySQL only?

======================================

## UPDATE:

With all answers posted so far I get the error message #1054 `Unknown column 'p.bulk_reference' in 'field list'.` I have no idea why this happens...

This is the adaptation of one of the answers posted:

```
SELECT p.id , 
   IF(p.bulk_reference>0,r.sales_price,p.sales_price) AS sales_price 
   , p.bulk_reference 
   , p.bulk_count 
FROM products_attribs_cz p 
LEFT JOIN products_attribs_cz r ON r.id = p.bulk_reference 
AND p.bulk_reference > 0 
WHERE p.id=166;
```

However, whatever solution posted I have tried, I always get the error...

The ID is unique in this table. The field that is being selected changes and is generated dynamically. There is always only one result. Not several. I am always selecting a unique row, however, it's a bulk package of products. So for example we have a BlackBerry phone on row ID=1 & product_name=BlackBerry. But on another row (ID=2) we have a bulk package of the same phone, so ID=2 & product_name=blank & bulk_reference=1. We need to return the name of the product from the bulk_referenced row as it's the same product, only in bulk packaging.

(the idea is that wholesellers get discounts on bulk orders. so if the order 1 phone they get normal price, if they order a bulk of 10 phones they get 20% off)

Comment: Is the `product_name = NULL` if `bulk_reference = 0`?

Comment: not sure if I understand you. But see. We have 2 rows. One has all fields filled. The name, price etc (except bulk). The other row has only bulk_reference & bulk_count filled. So if I select `product_name` from row 2 (all fields blank except the bulk ones) the value should be taken over from the row that is referenced.

Comment: the query does not have to check whether there are values present or not, neither should it check for anything except `bulk_reference`. If this is set = take values from the referenced row. If not, take from current row. (bulk_reference = 0 by default)

Comment: @Michal: I don't see anything wrong with your query. It looks fine to me. The most logical explanation is that `bulk_reference` is not a valid column name in the `products_attribs_cz` table.  (Thanks for the clarification on the specification. That's what your query should be doing... checking only the value in the `bulk_reference` column to make the determination of whether a lookup is required.

Comment: @spencer7593 I've commented on your answer, you're completely right, it was missing there....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to get the result using a LEFT JOIN, (assuming we are guaranteed that the `id` column is UNIQUE on the products table):

```
SELECT p.id
     , IF(p.bulk_reference>0,r.product_name,p.product_name) AS product_name
     , p.price
     , p.bulk_reference
     , p.bulk_count
  FROM products p
  LEFT
  JOIN products r
    ON r.id = p.bulk_reference AND p.bulk_reference > 0
```

The `LEFT JOIN` says to return all the rows from the table on the left, along with any "matching" row from the table on the right side. In this case, we only need a "matching" row if the value of the bulk_reference column is greater than zero, so we can include that condition in a predicate in the `ON` clause.

The "trick" is to use a conditional test in the SELECT list. If the bulk_reference column is greater than zero, we return the name from the parent row, otherwise, we return the value from the current row.

(If we don't have a guarantee that `id` is unique, that query will need to be modified to guarantee that the returned resultset matches the specification.)

Another way to get an equivalent result would be to use a correlated subquery in the SELECT list. (This is not the most efficient approach, but it works suitably for a small number of rows being returned.)

```
SELECT p.id
     , IF(p.bulk_reference > 0,
           ( SELECT r.product_name
               FROM products r
              WHERE r.id = p.bulk_reference
              ORDER BY r.id
              LIMIT 1
           ), p.product_name
       ) AS product_name
     , p.price
     , p.bulk_reference
     , p.bulk_count
  FROM products p
```

What that's going to do is: if the `bulk_reference` column value is greater than zero, MySQL will execute the subquery to return a `product_name` value from the referenced row. Otherwise (i.e. if `bulk_reference` is null or not greater than zero, the value stored in the `product_name` column on the row will be returned.

---

NOTE: The queries above only get the value of the `product_name` from the referenced row; they do not do a test on the referenced row, and take into account that the product_name on that referenced row will actually be retrieved from another parent row.

Consider, for example this set of rows:

```
  id  product_name  price  bulk_reference
  --  ------------  -----  --------------
   1  fee           11.99  0             
   2  fi            22.99  0             
   3  fo            25.99  2
   4  fum           28.99  3
```

To get product_name from row id=4 returned as "fi", rather than "fo"...

```
SELECT p.id
     , IF(p.bulk_reference>0,
         IF(q.bulk_reference>0,
           IF(r.bulk_reference>0,s.product_name,r.product_name),
           q.product_name),
         p.product_name
       ) AS product_name
     , p.price
     , p.bulk_reference
     , p.bulk_count
  FROM products p
  LEFT
  JOIN products q
    ON q.id = p.bulk_reference AND q.bulk_reference > 0
  LEFT
  JOIN products r
    ON r.id = q.bulk_reference AND r.bulk_reference > 0
  LEFT
  JOIN products s
    ON s.id = r.bulk_reference AND s.bulk_reference > 0
```

Comment: I have tried to implement it, but I always get the error `Unknown column 'p.bulk_reference' in 'field list'.`

Comment: @Michal: you would need to post the query you tried to implement, in order to debug that. I assigned the alias `p` to the `products` table, so `p.bulk_reference` is a valid reference, as long as column name `bulk_reference` is in the `products` table.

Comment: @spencer7592 - I have updated the question with the full query as generated by my system... please note that the table is more complex as I posted in the original question (it has 30+ columns), ID is unique... the field being selected and the table name change so they are generated dynamically... furthermore the `WHERE` condition is dynamic too...

Comment: damn it... you're right... there are several tables... `products_attribs_cz`, `products_attribs_sk`, `products_attribs_en` etc... I forgot to add the bulk fields to some of the tables... thanx for pointing me to this... it seems to work now :)

Comment: one more question. Can I select all fields with a *? Like `SELECT p.*, IF(p.bulk_reference>0`?

Comment: Using `p.*` in the SELECT list is valid syntax, there is nothing stopping you from doing that. There may be some good reasons for doing that. But my personal preference is to avoid that, and to explicitly specify a list of expressions and column names to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this for your specific example:

```
SELECT P2.Product_Name
FROM Products P
  INNER JOIN Products P2 ON P.Bulk_Reference = P2.Id
WHERE P.Id = 3
```

And to return all product names:

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN P.Bulk_Reference = 0 THEN P.Product_Name 
    ELSE COALESCE(P2.Product_Name,'Unknown') END Product
FROM Products P
  LEFT JOIN Products P2 ON P.Bulk_Reference = P2.Id
```

In case Bulk_Reference > 0 AND Product_Name is NULL, I added Unknown.  This assume Product_Name is NULL and not blank.  If blank, add

```
COALESCE(NULLIF(P2.Product_Name,''),'Unknown')
```

--EDIT

I didn't see that you wanted to return all the row values from the reference field where the value is blank.  The above query will work just the same way -- just add your fields.

```
SELECT P.Id, 
    CASE WHEN P.Bulk_Reference = 0 THEN P.Product_Name 
    ELSE COALESCE(P2.Product_Name,'Unknown') END Product_Name, 
    CASE WHEN P.Bulk_Reference = 0 THEN P.Price 
    ELSE COALESCE(P2.Price,'Unknown') END Price,
    P.Bulk_Reference,
    CASE WHEN P.Bulk_Reference = 0 THEN P.Bulk_Count
    ELSE COALESCE(P2.Bulk_Count,0) END Bulk_Count
FROM Products P
  LEFT JOIN Products P2 ON P.Bulk_Reference = P2.Id
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
select
  m.id,
  IF(m.product_name is null,l.product_name,m.product_name) as ProductName,
  m.bulk_reference
from mytable as m
  LEFT JOIN mytable as l ON l.id = m.bulk_reference
```

If product_name is null it will fetch from joined table.